# VS Code Unverified Breakpoints Firefox

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, firefox, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug my TypeScript app in VS Code with Firefox. But all my breakpoints are greyed out and marked as "Unverified Breakpoint".

My project structure is as follows:

[image]

My launch.json looks as follows:

[image]

I can debug the app directly in Firefox

[image]

I have tried different versions for the webroot path but none did work.